# SQL Query to get 1 output from 2 different columns within same table

Tags: sql

I am still new to SQL and was wondering what would be the best option to get distinct category names from two different columns from the same table.

Example:

```
Table Name: Fruits

ID          CAT1           CAT2
1           APPLE          PEACH
2           PEACH          GRAPE
3           APPLE          GRAPE
4           ORANGE         APPLE
5           PEACH          PEAR
```

Desired Output

```
Distinct CAT
APPLE
PEACH
GRAPE
ORANGE
PEAR
```

I know that I would want to do a join where I name each table a letter like fruits a and fruits b so I match it via the ID but I cannot figure how to display it in one column only the distinct CAT from both columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query the distinct values of both columns separately and UNION (e.g. [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)) the results:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT CAT1 FROM Fruits)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT CAT2 FROM Fruits)
```

Comment: Thanks I was way over thinking this

Answer (score 1):

If you would have played with it little you would have get this already.

Select distinct cat from ( (Select cat1 as cat from fruits) union all (Select cat2 as cat from fruits)) q

Comment: Yes I was only thinking of using join I completely forgot the purpose of Union which was why my queries were not working